# Memory leak with resize in drawImage

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas

Link from my plugin:
https://github.com/luisdemarchi/cordova-plugin-facedetection-lite

Link from my finally code:
https://github.com/luisdemarchi/example-cordova-facedetection/blob/master/www/index.html

**Problem:**
I'm running JavaScript in an iOS app (Cordova), when I crop a Canvas with many pixels, reducing that cut to a desired size, it is possible to keep up with a memory growth until its limit and application closes.

**What am I doing:**
I am creating my first public repository, which will be a facial detection component for Cordova . There is a script called "pico" in C and a translation in JavaScript, I used these libraries for my plugin and in the Browser everything is perfect, however in iOS (where I created a lib from the C library) I am having memory leak that happens several steps after calling the method in C. The problem is apparently in the sample code and not in the library.

**IOS Code Flow:**

- A plugin opens the native iOS camera and converts the frames into a
  HTML Canvas;
- I have function loop in set timeout of 20 milliseconds:
- that copies the image of this Canvas and creates another one, with the limit size of 90 pixels of height and width;
- Send this image reduced to the plugin that returns in the coordinates of the detected faces;
- In parallel, while the first canvas update the frames, use the latest coordinated face to cut again this Canvas and put on third Canvas;

[image]

**What I tried:**

- I removed the frame resize by requestAnimationFrame();
- In context I add beginPath();
- Set the variables to null;
- Call "function" delete
- **if wait 1 second to call the method that cuts the face, this prevents memory leakage;**

**Code**

```
var updateFacePreview = function () {
    var loop = function () {
        if (faceBox.x > 0) {
            var facePreview = document.getElementById("facePreview");
            var facePreviewCtx = facePreview.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });
            facePreviewCtx.beginPath();
            facePreviewCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
            // console.log("x: " + parseInt(faceBox.x / scale) + " y: " + parseInt(faceBox.y / scale) + " size: " + parseInt(faceBox.size / scale));
            facePreviewCtx.drawImage(
                isIosApp ? cameraIosPreview : cameraPreview,
                parseInt(faceBox.x / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.y / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
                0,
                0,
                400,
                400
            );
            delete facePreviewCtx;
            delete facePreview;
            delete cameraIosPreviewTemp;
            cameraIosPreviewTemp = null;
            facePreviewCtx = null;
            facePreview = null;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    // window.setTimeout(function () {
    //     updateFacePreview();
    // }, 100);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that if I do not change the size of the image, at the time of the cut, there is no memory leak. However if make the cut with 1 pixel bigger or smaller, the leak occurs.

Here's the snippet that works:

```
facePreviewCtx.drawImage(
    isIosApp ? cameraIosPreview : cameraPreview,
    10, 10, 300, 300,
    0, 0, 300, 300
);
```

An example of a memory leak occurs (Only running JS in UIWebView on iOS):

```
facePreviewCtx.drawImage(
    isIosApp ? cameraIosPreview : cameraPreview,
    10, 10, 300, 300,
    0, 0, 150, 150
);
```

Comment: Most probably you memory leak doesn't come from what you've shown, but note that `delete` doesn't work like that... It only deletes object's properties, on orphan variables it does nothing.

Comment: @Kaiido I came to the conclusion that the leak happens when drawing on the canvas because if I create a black square instead of using drawImage, and keeping all the rest of the code, there is no memory leak.

Comment: I'm not entitled to talk about your cordova code, but from a glance, your `malloc` are more likely to cause memory leaks than hardly tested browser's drawImage.

Comment: @Kaiido I was able to reduce some malloc's I had used. But I discovered that the error really only happens in reducing the cut field, I added the example code

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked:**

I'm creating a temporary HTML Canvas, which captures the face at the original size without reducing it, and then I make the cutout for the other HTML Canvas just by reducing the size.

This solution inelegant, but this avoids memory leakage. Following source code:

```
var updateFacePreview = function () {
    var loop = function () {
        if (faceBox.x > 0) {
            var faceSizeOriginal = document.createElement('canvas');
            faceSizeOriginal.width = parseInt(faceBox.size / scale);
            faceSizeOriginal.height = parseInt(faceBox.size / scale);
            var faceSizeOriginalCtx = faceSizeOriginal.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });
            faceSizeOriginalCtx.drawImage(
                isIosApp ? cameraIosPreview : cameraPreview,
                parseInt(faceBox.x / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.y / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
                0,
                0,
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
                parseInt(faceBox.size / scale),
            );

            facePreviewCtx.drawImage(
                faceSizeOriginal,
                0, 0, faceSizeOriginal.width, faceSizeOriginal.height,
                0, 0, 400, 400
            );

            cameraIosPreviewTemp = null;
            faceSizeOriginal = null;
            faceSizeOriginalCtx = null;
            facePreview = null;
            delete faceSizeOriginalCtx;
            delete faceSizeOriginal;
            delete facePreview;
            delete cameraIosPreviewTemp;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```